# Sumif array formula with nested if function only returning total on first value in array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sumif formula wrapped in a sum formula so I can use an array where if the value in cell G2 equals "All" then I want to add up the values in range B2:B4 for three names in the data, but if the value cell G2 equals one of the three names, ie: Tim, then I just want to add up all the values in range B2:B4 for Tim. The formula works fine if only one name is used, but when I enter "All" into cell G2, only the value for the first name is added up. I'm using the below formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A2:A4,IF(G2="All",{"Tim","Henry","Mike"},G2),B2:B4))
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas on how to get this to work.

Comment: So I assume your sum-range is larger and there is a lookup column with names? Can you show sample data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case these three values are the only occuring values in your list, you could just put this in an `IF` statement, like so:

```
=IF(G2="All",SUM(B2:B4),SUMIF(A2:A4,G2,B2:B4))
```

[image]

If you have other names in your lookup column, like so:

[image]

Your own formula work just fine using it as array formula. You just had to enter it through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You could use a formula like:

```
=IF(G2="All",SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A2:A5,{"Tim","Henry","Mike"},B2:B5)),SUMIF(A2:A5,G2,B2:B5))
```

To prevent you have to enter it as array (it's still technically an array formula!)

Answer (score 0):

No need to hard code the array or for an array formula:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,IF(G2="All","*",G2),B:B)
```

Comment: True, I'm just guessing there are more then these three values, and these three names represent 'All'. Why else would OP try to put them into an array?